# Is it possible to have two or more gateways in the same network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

In the area where I live, I have the possibility to use three internet networks. Now, my house has a wired network where in practice through TP-Link repeaters I would like to "convey" the three different networks on the same cable. The main network where I work must remain the one that is auto-configured, but if I connect a computer to the main network, and manually change the parameters, entering those of the second gateway (example, 192.168.2.1 instead of 192.168.1.1 which would be the main one), I wonder if the two networks can coexist on the same cable. This thing would be very useful for me because I often find myself working with external servers to which I have to upload several GB of data, but which, for obvious reasons, saturate my home network when uploading.

Comment: This is only useful if you have more than one ISP and a router from each one (including two connections/cables from both ISPs to your house).

Comment: Yeah, i have more ISP

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible and sometimes it has a valid use.

However, I consider your setup too complicated. It will be easier to have all gateways in the same subnet, e.g. `192.168.1.1` for the first, `192.168.1.2` for the second and so on, configure DHCP service only on one of them, and add additional routes to certain addresses via other gateway.

Comment: But if I do this, I run the risk that the ISP - 2 devices will then be reconfigured to navigate all on a single line. I would like the networks to remain separate and possibly connect with a manual configuration made ad hoc.